# Primefaces dialog vs regular page - which better?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, updates

A simple task of updating data is usually performed by showing dataTable with rows, allowing to select row we intend to change, and...

and I can use **primefaces dialog** to display a form populated from dataTable or I can achieve the same by redirecting to standard jsf **page** with populated inputs, and commandButtons refering to actions in backing bean.

So I can do update (content of table) both ways, through primefaces dialog or standard jsf page. Is your experience suggesting that one way of realization update is better than other? Is it only a question of look and feel? Are there some important advantages or good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the dialog box form is short, i.e. only 3-4 fields are to be
  updated and we do not deal with the data immediately, I would prefer
  dialog box.
- But if it is a large form or some more operations are to be performed even after submitting, I would like to redirect to another page.
- Primefaces dialog box will submit the request with the help of ajax and if the method bound is in the same managed bean, then the data of thea bean will be available for any operations.
- If you are redirecting to some other page, then you will have to stuff the data in request and again retrieve it back there.

According to me, dialog box will be a nice pick if operations are small and of course for look and feel.

Ohh yes... while dealing with primefaces, make sure everyone is using latest browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Some point of views about using the **dialog**:

- functional: I would prefer the dialog if it can help to enrich an action on a specific field, which is part of a wider feature, for example an user creation page might use a dialog to load and choose user's city of birth.
- look and feel: using dialog might require little extra work to realize a responsive layout
- security: using dialog might require some extra work, often you put the dialog in your output page just as an hidden component, and with browser's dev tools someone might be able to make the dialog visible and perform undesired operations.